# Where can I download mobilenet_v1_160res_0.5_imagenet_labels.txt for local testing?

Tags: google-aiy

For our course projects, we started off with Google's AIY Vision kit. I am looking into how to use output for next level processing. We are all newbies to ML

I am testing image classification using sources from [Github AIY Projects](https://github.com/google/aiyprojects-raspbian) on my mac.

```
python image_classification.py -i images/cat01.jpeg
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/aiy/models/mobilenet_v1_160res_0.5_imagenet_labels.txt'
```

I would like to test this to see output format that I want to use for next steps.

Where can I get the labels txt file?

I found a good [Coral link](https://coral.withgoogle.com/models/) that has TPU models and labels. Is there a way to use this instead?

Answer (score 0):

couldn't get it to work on my mac but tried to create a [dockerfile](https://gitlab.com/mayanktahil/rosie/blob/master/dockerfile) for some of the AIY example codes to run on a docker host within the mac.

The missing piece to overcome the error you listed above for me was to :

`apt-get install -y aiy-models` after adding the Debian repo source. Not sure how to get around that on the mac.